# Не работает .btn-mini в Boostrap

Tags: bootstrap

Код:

```
 <div class="btn-group ">
    <a class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" href="#">Запись</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-mini" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Редактировать</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Удалить</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Пытаюсь создать Кнопка-список, но не могу отредактировать размер кнопки, применяю классы но никакого эффекта. Вот по этому мануалу http://bootstrap-ru.com/204/components.php . 
Также у меня почему-то не работают иконки Icon glyphs. 
`<i class="icon-search"></i>` не пашет.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Какую версию bootstrap Вы используете?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, вы используйте 3 версию Bootstrap, а смотрите документацию по 2й. 
http://bootstrap-3.ru/index.php - 3 на русском языке